# How to globally modify the default PYTHONPATH (sys.path)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, path

On a Ubuntu (10.10) system, I have a Python package that installs itself into `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`. This isn't contained in the default path (sys.path). How do I add this directory to the path?

Setting the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable is a solution, of course, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this. For example `easy_install` also puts installed packages in it, my sys.path looks something like this:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/keyring-0.5.1-py2.6.egg', 
'/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',  
'/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', 
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
```

so the path is obviously not the default built into the Python binary.

Is there a single config file that contains the entries above? Or in what ways is it possible to modify it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [site module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) and [Modifying Python's Search Path](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path) seem to be what you're looking for.

As far as I understand it, those entries are being added to `sys.path` by:

- `/usr/lib/python2.6/site.py`
- `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/site.py`
  (Change 2.6 to your version of Python.)

The easiest way to change it is to add a file `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/site-packages.pth` containing `../site-packages`.

Alternatively, maybe you can teach the package to use `site.getsitepackages()`?

Comment: thanks, works perfectly :) (I ended up adding a .pth file to /usr/local/python2.6/dist-packages, containing "../site-packages")

Comment: You can also create a module called `sitecustomize.py` which `site.py` tries to import and modify `sys.path` there.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to summarize my findings about python's path modification. There are two ways to do it.

- *.pth* file
- `PYTHONPATH`

**Any** *.pth* file which is found on the default path (see bellow) will get its content included into `sys.path`.
Format of said *.pth* file is simple: one (folder) path per line. Surprisingly, the paths can be absolute or relative to the *.pth* file.

Default path is where the interpreter resides and `<some-prefix>/lib/python<version>/site-packages` where `<some-prefix>` is usually `/usr/`.

`PYTHONPATH` is environmental variable of your operating system. On unix systems you list them by `env`. Global modification of such variables is done through *.sh* scripts inside `/etc/profile.d/` folder as mentioned by @TestUser16418.

Comment: It is PYTHONPATH without "_"

Answer (score 6):

You might create a new file called `/etc/profile.d/local_python.sh` with the contents

```
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/":"${PYTHONPATH}"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Which will set the `PYTHONPATH` variable for all logged in users on your system.

Comment: This really isn't universal. The /etc/profile.d mechanism will only work for login shells for people with shells that use /etc/profile.d (bash/ksh/zsh). I'm sure csh users won't see this change. Also, will be ignored in cron/at jobs.

Comment: this is a nice way to set global environment variables (yet another thing I learned today), but as I mentioned in the post, I was looking for a more Pythonic way :)

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want to import the `suds` module which is available as an `.egg` file:

```
egg_path = '/home/shahid/suds_2.4.egg'

sys.path.append(egg_path)

import suds
# ... rest of code
```